# How to trigger a tutorial on first app launch(Android)

Tags: java, android

I need to start an activity(tutorial) on my first app launch. I figured i could write this in my main but then i realized once the app is closed and start again it would just start the tutorial again.

```
Boolean first = true;
if(first){
  Intent i ......
   first = false;
```

}

so i thought about creating a database or writing a value in a file and saving the Boolean value in that. Is there a easier way for this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preference for this. You can implement following codes on your onCreate method

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean first = prefs.getBoolean("key_first_launch", true);
if (first)
    // show your tutorial
else
    // dont show your tutorial
```

When first tutorial complete, change preference value

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences(getApplicationContext());
prefs.edit().putBoolean("key_first_launch", false).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save that information, for instance with SharedPreferences, so that it is persistent and read its value when the application is started.

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#preferences